# How do I get values from a SQL database into textboxes using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sqldatareader

I'm creating a booking management system and I am having problems trying to get data from a SQL database and insert into a group of textboxes of my application.

I want to show the customer details, when a button is clicked, in a DataGridView, but when I click the button, the application throws an exception with the following error message;

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UToqg.png) of the screen where I want to view customer details, and the code for the button, which will eventually show customer details in the respective textboxes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=LoginScreen;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        com.Connection = sc;
        sc.Open();
        SqlDataReader read = (null);
        com.CommandText = ("select * from Pending_Tasks");
        read = com.ExecuteReader();
        CustID.Text = (read["Customer_ID"].ToString());
        CustName.Text = (read["Customer_Name"].ToString());
        Add1.Text = (read["Address_1"].ToString());
        Add2.Text = (read["Address_2"].ToString());
        PostBox.Text = (read["Postcode"].ToString());
        PassBox.Text = (read["Password"].ToString());
        DatBox.Text = (read["Data_Important"].ToString());
        LanNumb.Text = (read["Landline"].ToString());
        MobNumber.Text = (read["Mobile"].ToString());
        FaultRep.Text = (read["Fault_Report"].ToString());
        sc.Close();
```

Comment: You're not reading anything! You execute it, but you don't iterate through the reader! Use `while(read.Read())` - please note, if there are more than 1 set of results, only the last set will be saved.

Comment: Check out this link over here http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/155444/how-to-display-data-from-sql-database-to-textbox-u

Comment: you are missing `read.Read()` call

Comment: do you have any date in your table Pending_tasks? if yes then you should first do read.Read() and then assign values

Comment: You can also wrap the connection in a using block, to ensure it gets closed. Some folks recommend still doing the close in finally.

Comment: thanks for all the helpful answers, it turns out I did indeed need to use while(read.Read()) and it works perfectly now! thankyou very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line `reader.Read()` is missing in your code. You should add it. It is the function which actually reads data from the database:

```
string conString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=LoginScreen;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);

string selectSql = "select * from Pending_Tasks";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(selectSql, con);

try
{
    con.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            CustID.Text = (read["Customer_ID"].ToString());
            CustName.Text = (read["Customer_Name"].ToString());
            Add1.Text = (read["Address_1"].ToString());
            Add2.Text = (read["Address_2"].ToString());
            PostBox.Text = (read["Postcode"].ToString());
            PassBox.Text = (read["Password"].ToString());
            DatBox.Text = (read["Data_Important"].ToString());
            LanNumb.Text = (read["Landline"].ToString());
            MobNumber.Text = (read["Mobile"].ToString());
            FaultRep.Text = (read["Fault_Report"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

**EDIT :** This code works supposing you want to write the last record to your textboxes. If you want to apply a different scenario, like for example to read all the records from database and to change data in the texboxes when you click the `Next` button, you should create and use your own Model, or you can store data in the DataTable and refer to them later if you wish.

Comment: If there are multiple rows, this will overwrite the textboxes until the last row is read.

Comment: yes I know this. he can either write first info to textboxes or  last one.

Comment: I am glad that it worked for you. But keep in mind that it will overwrite records in textboxes if there are more than one row. Thanks @DavidS. for commenting

Answer (score 3):

```
using (SqlConnection connection =  new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=LoginScreen;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    SqlCommand command =
    new SqlCommand("select * from Pending_Tasks WHERE CustomerId=...", connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader read= command.ExecuteReader();

    while (read.Read())
    {
        CustID.Text = (read["Customer_ID"].ToString());
        CustName.Text = (read["Customer_Name"].ToString());
        Add1.Text = (read["Address_1"].ToString());
        Add2.Text = (read["Address_2"].ToString());
        PostBox.Text = (read["Postcode"].ToString());
        PassBox.Text = (read["Password"].ToString());
        DatBox.Text = (read["Data_Important"].ToString());
        LanNumb.Text = (read["Landline"].ToString());
        MobNumber.Text = (read["Mobile"].ToString());
        FaultRep.Text = (read["Fault_Report"].ToString());
    }
    read.Close();
}
```

Make sure you have data in the query : **select * from Pending_Tasks** and you are using "using System.Data.SqlClient;"

Answer (score 2):

`read = com.ExecuteReader()`

`SqlDataReader` has a function `Read()` that reads the next row from your query's results and returns a `bool` whether it found a next row to read or not. So you need to check that before you actually get the columns from your reader (which always just gets the current row that `Read()` got). Or preferably make a loop `while(read.Read())` if your query returns multiple rows.

Comment: @EhsanUllah yes OP should restrict the query on primary key or store results from each `Read()` in another fashion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display single value access from database into textbox, please refer to the code below:

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("connection string");
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlConnection(SqlQuery,Con);
Con.Open();
TextBox1.Text=cmd.ExecuteScalar();
Con.Close();
```

or

```
SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("connection string");
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlConnection(SqlQuery,Con);
Con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr=new SqlDataReadr();
dr=cmd.Executereader();
if(dr.read())
{
    TextBox1.Text=dr.GetValue(0).Tostring();
}
Con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a connection and open it.

```
con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=<database_name>)));User Id =<userid>; Password =<password>");
con.Open();
```

Write the select query:

```
string sql = "select * from Pending_Tasks";
```

Create a command object:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
```

Execute the command and put the result in a object to read it.

```
OracleDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

now start reading from it.

```
while (read.Read())
{
 CustID.Text = (read["Customer_ID"].ToString());
 CustName.Text = (read["Customer_Name"].ToString());
 Add1.Text = (read["Address_1"].ToString());
 Add2.Text = (read["Address_2"].ToString());
 PostBox.Text = (read["Postcode"].ToString());
 PassBox.Text = (read["Password"].ToString());
 DatBox.Text = (read["Data_Important"].ToString());
 LanNumb.Text = (read["Landline"].ToString());
 MobNumber.Text = (read["Mobile"].ToString());
 FaultRep.Text = (read["Fault_Report"].ToString());
}
read.Close();
```

Add this too using **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;**