# SqlDataReader stops reading values if null is present in table

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader

I am using a `SqlDataReader` to read values to database and then storing the values in appropriate textboxes. The code is working fine if there is no null value in the row but if there is one, it stops reading all the values after it has encountered null and displays blanks in all textboxes.

This is the code I am using :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString.ToString());

con.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT dbo.asp2.CustomerName, dbo.asp2.Email,
dbo.asp2.CP, dbo.asp2.CPN, dbo.asp2.ProductName, dbo.asp2.Warranty,
dbo.asp2.ProductSerial, dbo.asp2.ProductNumber, dbo.asp2.Description,
dbo.asp2.IssueDate, dbo.asp2.Status, dbo.asp2.Remarks, 
dbo.asp2.EngineerName from dbo.asp2 where ID='" + textBox1.Text + "'";

cmd.Connection = con;

rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    textBox3.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
    textBox4.Text = rdr.GetString(1);
    textBox5.Text = rdr.GetString(2);
    textBox6.Text = rdr.GetString(3);
    textBox7.Text = rdr.GetString(4);
    textBox8.Text = rdr.GetString(5);
    textBox9.Text = rdr.GetString(6);
    textBox10.Text = rdr.GetString(7);
    textBox11.Text = rdr.GetString(8);
    textBox2.Text = rdr.GetDateTime(9).ToString();
    textBox12.Text = rdr.GetString(10);
    textBox13.Text = rdr.GetString(11);
    comboBox1.Text = rdr.GetString(12);  
}
con.Close();
```

I can't seem to figure out the problem here. Could you point it out? What I need it to do is, set the textboxes empty where there is a null value and if there is a value in table then set that value to textbox.

P.S all the values I am retrieving are stored as `nvarchar` in database except for `IssueDate` which is in `smalldatetime`.

Comment: Probably your code that is calling the above has a try/catch that is swallowing the exception thrown when the reader encounters a null value.  Either test for null (rdr.IsDBNull), or you can also use ToString() to convert null values to an empty string (e.g. rdr[0].ToString())

Comment: Tried what you suggested. Still same problem.

Comment: Once you've fixed the actual stopping issues, you might also want to read up on SQL injection and then on using parameters.

Comment: @HenkHolterman What do you mean by that? I am reading all the records. My code is working perfectly if there is no null value in the specific row of the table. 
If there is, it stops reading at that point.

Comment: I am learning C#, so I googled and this is where I got my code from to retrieve multiple values from database into textboxes 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565035/how-do-i-get-values-from-a-sql-database-into-textboxes-using-c

Comment: @HenkHolterman Could you refer me to a tutorial where I could get help from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem (reader stopped after encountering null), what I did was :

I replaced this :

```
textBox3.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
```

with this :

```
textBox3.Text = rdr["ColumnName"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

> while (rdr.Read()) {
>
> if (rdr.IsDBNull(0))
>       { textBox3.Text = rdr.GetString(0); }  else    { textBox3.Text = "";  }
>
> ---- For Datetime
>
> if (rdr.IsDBNull(9))
>       { textBox2.Text =  rdr.GetDateTime(9).ToString(); }  else    { textBox2.Text = "";  }
>
> }